# KeyError: 'PYSPARK_GATEWAY_SECRET' when creating spark context inside aws lambda code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-lambda, py4j, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I have deployed a lambda function which uses sparknlp, as a docker container. For working with sparknlp I need spark context. So, In my sparknlp code, I start with

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext().getOrCreate()
```

I tested my lambda on local and it worked fine.

On aws I got this error :

```
java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

even though JAVA_HOME was properly set.

I found out in the source code :
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py
in the launch_gateway method that it tries to create a temporary file and if that file is not created it raises the above error. (line 105)

Lambda won't allow write access to file system, so the file cannot be created.

So I am trying to pass gateway_port and gateway_secret as environment variables.

I have kept the `PYSPARK_GATEWAY_PORT=25333` which is the default value.
I am not able to figure out how to get the `PYSPARK_GATEWAY_SECRET`.

Which is why getting the error :

```
KeyError: 'PYSPARK_GATEWAY_SECRET'
```